# "so... that..." emphasizing construction

Tags: phrases

What's the right way of using this "so... that..." emphasizing construction?

> At times her guesses are **so accurate, it makes** me suspect that she has
>   some special ability to read my mind.
>
> At times her guesses are **so accurate, that it makes** me suspect that she has
>   some special ability to read my mind.

Do I need "that" or can I drop it?

Also, is comma necessary there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma should be deleted. What follows is essential information to the meaning of the sentence.

And 'that' may be omitted.